# Macro for calculating 100 percent ratio

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code in macro but giving wrong output when applied to my Excel sheet.

Background of what i need to do:
intial table

**STEP 1:**

[image: where to add formulas]

Fill in the excel table for columns from E2 to I5

Green rows:

example formula for cell E2   =D2*(100%+$A$3-$A$5)

Blue rows:

exmaple formula  for cell E4   =D4+D3-E3

**Result after step 1**

[image: Result after step 1]

step 2:

Where there is negative value, we have to replace it with "0"

**result after Step 2**

[image: result after Step 2]

step 3:
The sum of values in column H and I are more than 100, so we just replace the highest number with 100

**Final Result**

[image: Final Result Set]

Any help in correction of this code or making a new logic will be appreciated.

**code**

```vb
Sub ApplyFormulasWithConditions()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sumPositives As Double
    Dim maxVal As Double
   
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name
   
    ' Loop through the table and apply the formulas
    For i = 2 To 5 ' Rows 2 to 5
        For j = 5 To 9 ' Columns e to i
            If j = 6 Then
                ' Formula for F2
                ws.Cells(i, j).Formula = "=$E$" & i & "*(1+$B$3-$B$5)"
            ElseIf j = 7 Then
                ' Formula for F3
                ws.Cells(i, j).Formula = "=$E$" & i & "*(1+$B$3+$B$5)"
            Else
                ' Formulas for F4 to Q5
                ws.Cells(i, j).Formula = "=$E$" & i & "+E" & i & "-F" & i & ""
            End If
           
            ' Apply condition 1: If the value is negative, make it zero
            If ws.Cells(i, j).Value < 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i, j).Value = 0
            End If
           
            ' Apply condition 2: If the value is more than 100, calculate the sum of positive values and divide by the sum
            If ws.Cells(i, j).Value > 100 Then
                sumPositives = 0
                For k = 6 To 17 ' Calculate the sum of positive values in the same row
                    If ws.Cells(i, k).Value > 0 Then
                        sumPositives = sumPositives + ws.Cells(i, k).Value
                    End If
                Next k
                If sumPositives > 0 Then
                    ws.Cells(i, j).Value = ws.Cells(i, j).Value * (sumPositives / ws.Cells(i, j).Value)
                End If
            End If
           
            ' Apply condition 3: If the maximum value in a column is greater than 100, set all values to 100 and the others to zero
            If j = 6 Then
                maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, j), ws.Cells(5, j)))
                If maxVal > 100 Then
                    For k = 2 To 5 ' Rows 2 to 5
                        ws.Cells(k, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(100, ws.Cells(k, j).Value)
                    Next k
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What result is wrong?

Comment: @sam i'm not sure. i run all of it together so the whole result shows 0s

Comment: Maybe step through your code line-by-line, while monitoring the values of your variables and cells, to identify where the problem is. If you cannot then fix it, add further details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the formula instead?

```
E2 = IF(D2*(100%+$A$3-$A$5)<0,0,IF(D2*(100%+$A$3-$A$5)>1,1,D2*(100%+$A$3-$A$5)))

E4 = IF(D2*(D4+D3-E3)<0,0,IF(D2*(D4+D3-E3)>1,1,D2*(D4+D3-E3)))
```